# Does the equation have a unique solution, if..?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I have an statement thay says:

> The equation: $\frac{bx}{a} = \frac{ax + b^2}{a} - b, a \neq 0$, have
>   unique solution if:
>
> I) $a = b$
>
> II) $a > b$
>
> III) $a \neq b$

I know the properties to analyze the solutions of a first degree equation,

$ q \neq 0 $ have unique solutions
$ A = 0, B = 0 $ have infinite solutions

$ A = 0, B \neq 0 $ not have solutions,

I also know formula, $ X = - \frac {B} {A} $,

but I can not find a way to address this problem, could you help me? The correct answer is $ D) $, but that does not interest me, I'm interested in learning it.

PD: I get that $(x -b)(b-a) = 0$, but i not know how it could help me.

Comment: A lot of the theorems and properties you are citing have to do with coefficients of quadratics of the form $ax^2+bx+c=0$.  In your problem however you have $a$'s and $b$'s appearing in completely different places.  I want to emphasize then that your $a$'s and $b$'s are *not* the same $a$'s and $b$'s in the theorems you cite.  To avoid confusion then, I suggest temporarily referring to the $a$'s and $b$'s from your theorems as capital letters instead to distinguish the two.

Comment: Thanks, edited @JMoravitz

Comment: Excuse me, I was wrong and I miss writing something in the equation, look at it now please

Comment: Okay, so you made it to $(x-b)(b-a)=0$.  Remember your properties of real numbers as an integral domain, that is to say, if you have two numbers (or two parenthesis in your case) that multiply to be zero that implies that at one or both of them must be zero.  So, $(x-b)(b-a)=0$ implies that either $(x-b)=0$ or that $(b-a)=0$ (*or both are zero*)

Comment: Yes, $a = b$ But I do not know what that can help me solve it

Comment: Exactly, if $a=b$ then the statement would be true regardless the value of $x$ and you get no more information about $x$ at all and so there would be infinitely many solutions.  But, what about the situation that $a\neq b$?

Comment: It is also infinite solutions because $\frac{5}{5} = \frac{4}{4} ... $?

Comment: And also how can I know now, the case when $a \neq b$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Multiplying by $a\ne 0$ we get
$$x(b-a)=b^2$$
If $a=b$  we get $$0=b^2$$ So if $b=0$ then we get as the solution all real numbers. If $b\ne 0$ so we get no solution.
If $$a\ne b$$ we get $$x=\frac{b^2}{b-a}$$
With the new (corrected equation) you will get
$$x(b-a)=b(b-a)$$ or
$$(x-b)(b-a)=0$$
Now we have if $b=a$ then the solutions are all real numbers, and if $b\ne a$ then we get $x=b$

Comment: This not true, if we have $a=b$ then we get $$0=b^2$$ and the rest is what i have written.

Comment: Excuse me, I was wrong and I miss writing something in the equation, look at it now please

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner I will try to explain myself better.  We are given at the beginning of the problem that $a$ is a nonzero number.  In your initial case you look at the case where $b$ is a number equal to $a$ (*remembering that $a$ is a nonzero number*).  Since $b$ is equal to $a$, that should imply that $b$ is also nonzero by transitivity.  You then inspect a case where $b$ is simultaneously zero and nonzero, an impossibility.  While your conclusion in that case is fine, the premise of that case is false and so any conclusions made there are moot and should be recognized as such.

Comment: That is to say, the line following $0=b^2$ should read.  "And since $b=a$ and $a$ is nonzero we get that there are no solutions"  having completely skipped over the section discussing what happens with if $b=0$

Comment: Ok in this case you are right, but we have a new (corrected) equation!

Comment: Why when $ a \neq b $, you assume that $ x = b $

Comment: If $a\ne b$ we can divide by $a-b$ and we get $x=b$

Comment: We can divide, since it will be a real number, instead of indeterminate(dividing by zero if $a = b$)?

Comment: and what of $ a> b $, is also correct, that is also included in $ a \neq b $?

Comment: @Mattiu it is implied that they are looking for necessary and sufficient conditions such that the equation has a unique solution.  While $a>b$ is a sufficient condition it is not a necessary one.

Comment: Thanks four your help @JMoravitz and thanks Dr. Sonnhard

Answer (score 1):

The solution will be $a \neq b$, let me walk you through the whole reasoning step by step. Firstly, we can reorganise the equation a little bit to get a better idea of what is going on:

Your equation: $\frac{bx}{a} = \frac{ax+b^2}{a}-b$, by transferring everything to the right hand side, can be written as

$0 = \frac{(a-b)x+b^2}{a} - b = \frac{a-b}{a}x+\frac{b^2}{a}-b$, which is a linear function of x with two parameters, where $a \neq 0$ and $b \in \mathbb{R}$.

**Now we have three cases:**

**1)** A linear equation will have 0 solutions if its slope is zero and it is not identically equal to zero, as shown in the graph below:

[This image depicts the case when the slope is zero and the function has zero solutions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W6ElC.png)

The slope will be zero if and only if $\frac{a-b}{a}=0$, so $a = b$. Moreover, the function will not be identically equal to zero if we additionally have that $\frac{b^2}{a}-b \neq 0$, so $b(\frac{b}{a}-1) \neq 0$. This is equivalent to $b \neq 0$ or $a \neq b$, which in our case leaves only the first condition as valid.

**2)** The linear equation will have infinitely many solutions if it is identically equal to zero, meaning that its slope will be zero and it will cross the y-axis at zero. The graph below depicts this case:

[This image depicts the case when the function has infinitely many solutions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c6Rme.png)

In our case, the conditions above translate to: $\frac{(a-b)}{a}=0$, so $a=b$ and $\frac{b^2}{a}-b=0$, so $b=0$ or $a=b$. Hence, if $a=b$ the equation always has infinitely many solutions.

**3)** Finally, the linear equation will have one, unique, solution when it crosses the x axis in one point. This is depicted in the graph below.

[This image depicts the case when the function has one (unique) solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vJsvj.png)

This case happens whenever the slope of the function is not equal to zero. Just imagine, when the slope of a linear function is non-zero the function steadily increases or decreases. In such a case, at some point, it is doomed to hit zero.

In our case, this translates to $\frac{(a-b)}{a} \neq 0$, so $a\neq b$, which is the stated solution.

Comment: Matheusz, excuse me, but isnt is my equation, you forgot $-b$ at the end

Comment: Thank you Mattiu for pointing it out, it should now be correct.